# ABBYY OCR Does not recognize FRENCH characters

Tags: c#, ocr, abbyy

I just started to use ABBYY FineReader engine in C# environment. And I'm facing an recognition issue with some french pdf documents. The accent characters are not recognized, and some words do not seem to respect a dictionary check... Here is my code :

```
loader = new FREngine.InprocLoader();
engine = loader.InitializeEngine("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

IRecognizerParams rp = engine.CreateRecognizerParams();
rp.SetPredefinedTextLanguage("French");

document = engine.CreateFRDocumentFromImage(@"D:\test.pdf");

document.Process();

document.Export(@"D:\test.docx", FREngine.FileExportFormatEnum.FEF_DOCX, null);
```

I suspect the french configuration of the language for recognition is ignored. Have you got any ideas how to set it the right way ?

Comment: Did you ask their support?

Comment: Good idea, may be better to ask there than stackoverflow. I will update my question if I get an answer. Maybe interesting to have some of this OCR SDK code example on stack

Answer (score 0):

It works better with :

```
document = engine.CreateFRDocumentFromImage(@"D:\test.pdf");

DocumentProcessingParams dpp = engine.CreateDocumentProcessingParams();
dpp.PageProcessingParams.RecognizerParams.SetPredefinedTextLanguage("French");

document.Process(dpp);
```

French words and accent characters seems to be recognized. Although the result is not as good as the ABBYY cloud solution...

Comment: ABBYY Cloud represents a different (a bit older) version of the same technologies. You might have been missing a profile "DocumentRecognition_Accuracy".